# Calculate median of values in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I've got a piece of code (stored procedure) written in T-SQL that inserts into a table several data from a temporal table as shown here:

```
INSERT INTO [myschema].[CalculatedData](
    Year, 
    Month,
    Line,
    Car,
    Service,
    Route,
    Trip,
    Stop,
    Qty,
    CalculatedMean
  ) SELECT
    Year,
    Month,
    Line,
    Car,
    Service,
    Route,
    Trip,
    Stop,
    COUNT(*),
    AVG(Duration),  
  FROM
    @TableToCalculate
  GROUP BY
    Year,
    Month,
    Line,
    Car,
    Service,
    Route,
    Trip,
    Stop;
```

As you can see, I calculate the average (mean) of all the values. Easy, considering the built-in [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Now, what I want to do is to **calculate the median**. There isn't any function to calculate it, but as the median is equal to [calculating the 50th percentile](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-disc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), this can be used. But I don't know how to do it.

Any help, please?

Comment: Have you considered implementing the aggregate function in CLR?

Answer (score 6):

You can find a survey and performance comparison of the main SQL Server methods in Aaron Bertrand's articles [Best approaches for grouped median](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/02/t-sql-queries/grouped-median) and [What is the fastest way to calculate the median?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/median)

With suitable indexing, the method proposed by Peter Larsson often performs best, though the logic is a little trickier to follow. The following example is quoted from Aaron's first article, using a sales data set:

> ```
> SELECT d.SalesPerson, w.Median
> FROM
> (
>  SELECT SalesPerson, COUNT(*) AS y
>  FROM dbo.Sales
>  GROUP BY SalesPerson
> ) AS d
> CROSS APPLY
> (
>  SELECT AVG(0E + Amount)
>  FROM
>  (
>    SELECT z.Amount
>     FROM dbo.Sales AS z
>     WHERE z.SalesPerson = d.SalesPerson
>     ORDER BY z.Amount
>     OFFSET (d.y - 1) / 2 ROWS
>     FETCH NEXT 2 - d.y % 2 ROWS ONLY
>  ) AS f
> ) AS w(Median);
> ```

You might also be interested in reading my article about [Calculating the Median with a Dynamic Cursor](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/07/t-sql-queries/calculating-the-median-with-a-dynamic-cursor), which performs surprisingly well. I also have [Improving the Row Numbering Median Solution](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/07/sql-plan/improving-row-numbering-median) showing how to improve the performance of Peter's solution further.

Related Q & A here:

- [Using Percentile_Disc to compute Median/Interquartiles](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/120655/1192)

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY Year,Month) OVER (PARTITION BY Duration) AS Median
```

As in Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-disc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#:%7E:text=For%20a%20given%20percentile%20value,than%20or%20equal%20to%20P.), the PERCENTILE_DISC() function:

> Computes a specific percentile for sorted values in an entire rowset
> or within a rowset's distinct partitions in SQL Server. For a given
> percentile value P, PERCENTILE_DISC sorts the expression values in the
> ORDER BY clause.

For example, PERCENTILE_DISC (0.5) will compute the 50th percentile (that is, the median) of an expression. PERCENTILE_DISC calculates the percentile based on a discrete distribution of the column values. The result is equal to a specific column value.

Comment: It is better if the answer is obvious.  As it stands, viewers have to try it.  Please explain the various parts.